# MVC4: Is there a way to run codes even before the core assembly loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-assembly

I would like to run codes before even the main / core assembly (the project assembly) is being loaded into the server.

I want to run such as copy assembly code, which copy the updated assembly for the main application. So I want to copy the latest one then load that, after that all the referenced assembly follows. I want to do it from code / automatically every time the application is starting.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your application isn't running, so there's no way to run code that isn't running.
It sounds like you need build events to me?

Comment: Are you trying to do some auto-update of a web application? If so, then please don't do it with a pull from the web application but rather a push of the updated assemblies from the outside. For example you could have some build that produces updated assemblies of your application and as a next step it pushes them to the web servers to update the applications. Just follow the Continuous Delivery process. If it is not for updating purposes then please provide more details what exactly you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I heard of preapplicationstart attribute or startup method, but im not sure when those will be called? Before or after the assembly loading? What i want is to change the current core dll into the newer one. I also heard about shadow copying assembly, but i think it will only work on plugin assembly. The point is... I want to update my website programmatically.

Comment: OK if you want to update your website programatically you could write a script that will fetch the source code of your website from the repository, produce a new build of the website, run the unit tests, deploy it on a staging environment and run the integration tests and finally push it to your production servers. It all can (and should) be achieved programatically without any manual steps. You are just trying to solve a problem with a wrong approach.

Comment: `want to update my website programmatically` this sounds like a terrible idea. This is what a proper deployment process is for.

Comment: As a side note: since you mentioned preapplicationstart: this will execute at application startup but at this stage all assemblies from the bin folder will already be loaded in the AppDomain by ASP.NET.

Comment: In my case, doing push to application will be the last thing I will do. You mentioned about creating script. Is there a way to call script from mvc applications which will copy the updated assembly into the bin folder?

Comment: Of course that it's possible but you are inverting the entire process by doing it this way violating all good practices. I am just mentioning it for your own good, you could continue trying to invert the process of continuous delivery and hope for the best.

Comment: This is because my application is actaully an CMS app, or what about the appdomain thing? I heard we can create a new Appdomain and then move to the new one, delete the old one. Is this possible?

Comment: I have already provided my 2¢ on this topic and would prefer not to advocate bad practices by giving such solutions. After all StackOverflow is a site used by many people and would like to avoid anyone seeing this and, may God forbid, even implementing it :-) Hopefully someone else will provide you with a solution to this.

Comment: How is this a bad pratice? Could you explain?

Comment: You're massively over-complicating things by deciding to self-update, rather than going with the simple approach of using a Continuous Delivery process to push a new version of the application to replace the existing one. Self-update is really only a sensible solution for standalone software on machines you don't control (like Chrome's auto-update). If it's a web application and you own all the infrastructure, just use something like MSDeploy.

Comment: Im gonna sell my CMS so everyone can have the application, then they can auto update it. Much like joomla, wordpress, etc... but mine is MVC. Could you tell me how can I update those installed website by pushing? I dont think so